# How do I calculate the shortest and longest time intervals in R?

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have the following dataset called `phone` :

| TIMESTAMP | time | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 10:42:50.221 | 10:42:50 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 10:46:01.826 | 10:46:01 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 10:50:10.063 | 10:50:10 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 10:53:10.715 | 10:53:10 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 10:53:14.329 | 10:53:14 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 10:54:19.792 | 10:54:19 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 11:01:43.044 | 11:01:43 | 2021-01-12 |
| 2021-01-12 11:04:36.202 | 11:04:36 | 2021-01-12 |

I would like to calculate the time intervals between two consecutive `time` values for the entire dataset so that I can find the shortest and longest time intervals of the day. I've tried the following code, trying to calculate the time differences but it gives me negative values and I don't exactly know how accurate this is. I've tried changing the unit to minutes as well, but the output doesn't make sense to me.

```
v2 <- ymd_hms(phone$TIMESTAMP)
v1 <- difftime(v2[-length(v2)], v2[-1], unit = "hour")
```

Output of v1:

| x |
| --- |
| -0.0532236 hours |
| -0.0689547 hours |
| -0.0501811 hours |
| -0.0010039 hours |
| -0.0181842 hours |

How can I calculate the intervals and arrange them in descending order of the length?

dput of my data is as follows:

```
structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c("2021-01-12 10:42:50.221", "2021-01-12 10:46:01.826", 
"2021-01-12 10:50:10.063", "2021-01-12 10:53:10.715", "2021-01-12 10:53:14.329", 
"2021-01-12 10:54:19.792", "2021-01-12 11:01:43.044", "2021-01-12 11:04:36.202", 
"2021-01-12 11:07:36.636", "2021-01-12 11:18:59.169", "2021-01-12 11:25:44.954", 
"2021-01-12 11:25:54.263", "2021-01-12 11:26:25.414", "2021-01-12 11:28:05.471", 
"2021-01-12 11:30:24.349"), time = c("10:42:50", "10:46:01", 
"10:50:10", "10:53:10", "10:53:14", "10:54:19", "11:01:43", "11:04:36", 
"11:07:36", "11:18:59", "11:25:44", "11:25:54", "11:26:25", "11:28:05", 
"11:30:24"), date = structure(c(18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, `difftime(time1,time2)` calculates time1 - time2, and since your timestamps are ordered from earliest to latest, this difference will always be <=0. So one way to solve this is to shift both arguments by 1 place in opposite directions to get a positive result, ensuring that the first argument is always >= to the second argument.

```
df$diff=c(NA,difftime(tail(df$TIMESTAMP,-1),head(df$TIMESTAMP,-1),unit="hour"))
df[order(df$diff,decreasing=T),]

                 TIMESTAMP     time       date        diff
10 2021-01-12 11:18:59.169 11:18:59 2021-01-12 0.189592500
7  2021-01-12 11:01:43.044 11:01:43 2021-01-12 0.123125556
11 2021-01-12 11:25:44.954 11:25:44 2021-01-12 0.112718056
3  2021-01-12 10:50:10.063 10:50:10 2021-01-12 0.068954722
2  2021-01-12 10:46:01.826 10:46:01 2021-01-12 0.053223611
4  2021-01-12 10:53:10.715 10:53:10 2021-01-12 0.050181111
9  2021-01-12 11:07:36.636 11:07:36 2021-01-12 0.050120556
8  2021-01-12 11:04:36.202 11:04:36 2021-01-12 0.048099444
15 2021-01-12 11:30:24.349 11:30:24 2021-01-12 0.038577222
14 2021-01-12 11:28:05.471 11:28:05 2021-01-12 0.027793611
6  2021-01-12 10:54:19.792 10:54:19 2021-01-12 0.018184167
13 2021-01-12 11:26:25.414 11:26:25 2021-01-12 0.008653056
12 2021-01-12 11:25:54.263 11:25:54 2021-01-12 0.002585833
5  2021-01-12 10:53:14.329 10:53:14 2021-01-12 0.001003889
1  2021-01-12 10:42:50.221 10:42:50 2021-01-12          NA
```

Comment: Oy vey, I didn't think this through properly! Thank you so much for your answer, it's been very helpful.